# Compactified Boson on the cylinder vs. on the Torus

Tags: definition, conformal-field-theory, bosons

I am a little bit confused if there is a difference between the compactified boson on the torus and on the infinite cylinder.
In the big yellow book from Di Fransesco et altera, the formula for the conformal dimensions for the compactified boson on the torus are derived in chapter 10.4.1 (eq. 10.63 )and are given by

$h_{e,m}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{e}{R}+\frac{mR}{2})^2 \qquad \bar{h}_{e,m}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{e}{R}-\frac{mR}{2})^2$

while the ones for the compactified boson on the cylinder they read (they are only stated in eq 6.95):

$h_{n,m}=2\pi g(\frac{n}{4\pi g R}+\frac{mR}{2})^2 \qquad \bar{h}_{e,m}=2\pi g(\frac{n}{4\pi g R}-\frac{mR}{2})^2$

which seem very similar. Moreover, the book also says (page 351 below eq. 10.62) that the derived conformal weights for the torus are manifestly compatible with the one of the cylinder.

My question is now:

Are the models on the torus and on the cylinder somehow related, such that I should expect them to have the same conformal dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conformal dimensions of a given CFT are the same on any Riemann surface. Your torus and cylinder dimensions are equivalent. You just have to relate the parameters by
$$ R_\text{torus} = \sqrt{4\pi g}R_\text{cylinder} $$

Comment: Thank you very much!